# Why don't generic types whose respective type parameters conform to an inheritance relationship themselves conform to an analogous relationship?

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance

In Swift, when you have a `SubType` that inherits from some `SuperType`, and there is a `GenericType<TypeParameter>` which can accept as its `TypeParameter` instances of either class (`SubType` or `SuperType`), why is it that instances of the `GenericType<SubType>` are not convertible to `GenericType<SuperType>`?

I have heard that this behavior exists in other languages, and I would expect it to exist in Swift, so I am thirsty for insight here.

```
class SuperType {

}

class SubType: SuperType {

}

class GenericType<TypeParameter> {
    func someGenericFunction() {
        print(TypeParameter.self)
    }
}

let instance = GenericType<SuperType>()
let subInstance = GenericType<SubType>()

instance.someGenericFunction() // prints "SuperType"
subInstance.someGenericFunction() // prints "SubType"

let array: [GenericType<SuperType>] = [instance, subInstance] // throws error: cannot convert value of type 'SomeGenericClass<SubType>' to expected element type 'SomeGenericClass<SuperType>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is not easy way out...
If you want to put both object in an array, you can introduce some protocol which describes the desired behaviour

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func someGenericFunction()
}
```

And then make sure your `GenericType` conforms to it.

```
class GenericType<TypeParameter>: MyProtocol {
    func someGenericFunction() {
        print(TypeParameter.self)
    }
}
```

So.. then you can put your objects in `[MyProtocol]` array this way:

```
let instance = GenericType<SuperType>()
let subInstance = GenericType<SubType>()

instance.someGenericFunction() // prints "SuperType"
subInstance.someGenericFunction() // prints "SubType"

let array: [MyProtocol] = [instance, subInstance]
for object in array {
    object.someGenericFunction() // prints "SuperType", "SubType"
}
```